# How many villages are there at radar 20?

Tags: boom-beach

I know there are 42 resource bases (14 per resource); how many potentially gold-gathering villages are there? At radar 19, I'm counting 180 (160 owned, 3 PvE remaining, 17 PvP remaining).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Finally reached Radar 20; the answer is 191. I'm currently at 166 owned, 7 PvE remaining, 17 PvP remaining. The additional 1 is for Dr. T, who sneakily steals one VP and then gives it back each day.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, according to the [Boom Beach Wiki](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Radar), the answer is actually 233 islands.

Comment: Thanks, that indirectly answers it for me. 191+42 = 233. I realized the extra 1 was from Dr. T being there so often.